# Why the URL loses the '/edit' suffix after a failed validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I finally came to ask this question since I found no answer and it kept bothering me. What's the reason behind this behavior ? Is it REST-thingy-driven :) ?

I found this "workaround" but no explanation : [How to make a render :edit call show the /edit in the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348920/how-to-make-a-render-edit-call-show-the-edit-in-the-address-bar)

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

My question was not that well written, sorry. **Why the default Rails behavior is not to redirect to the edit template?** That would feel more logical, to me at least :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render` doesn't redirect, so there's no reason the URL bar address would change.

The default `update` method looks like this:

```
  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The URL is `/posts/1`, which is what displays in the URL bar. If [update_attributes fails, e.g., a validation error](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes), it renders the `"edit"` template, with no redirect.

Comment: @c_inconnu Because saving a model in flash is potentially expensive, especially since the default flash is limited to max cookie size, and a serialized model can be quite large. Also, IMO there's no good *reason* to change the URL.