# In my controller's update action, when update_attributes fails due to the validator, I lose the /edit suffix in my URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Description of my work environment: Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.3.1, SQL Server database, javascript on object html views

My controller that content an update action:

```
      if @cs.update_attributes(cs_params_update)
        flash[:notice] = "Centro de Saúde #{t(:record_successfully_updated)}"
        # format.html { render :action => 'edit', :cs_id => @cs.id  }
        # Permance na mesma página após o update
        format.html { redirect_to({:controller => :cs, :action=>:edit,
                                    :method => :get,
                                    :cs_id => @cs.id
                                    })}
        format.xml { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render({:controller => :cs, :action=> :edit }) }
        format.xml { render :xml => @cs.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
```

When I try to edit as follows http://localhost:3000/cs/1/edit and to save something that is going to call a validation erron on my controller's update action,
the validator display error validation as expected but instead rendering it redirects to show url as follows http://localhost:3000/cs/1 loosing the /edit suffix

I had previously seen this problem in some stackoverflow questions ->

[How to make a render :edit call show the /edit in the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348920/how-to-make-a-render-edit-call-show-the-edit-in-the-address-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Why the URL loses the '/edit' suffix after a failed validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593616/why-the-url-loses-the-edit-suffix-after-a-failed-validation?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In my case, I need to use :render, as my cancel button is sending me to the show due to the url and I can't go to the show, I need to stay in the edit after clicking the cancel button.

In my view I use javascript that allows you to enable and disable elements, follow the code present in my application.js:

```
function EnablDisablElements(FieldsNames, Status){
    if (FieldsNames) {
        for (var h = 0; h < FieldsNames.length; h++) {
            document.getElementById(FieldsNames[h]).disabled = Status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your question you spend the majority of the time focused on the fact that an edit submits the form to a different URL (and hence you "lost the `/edit` suffix"), and yet the links you shared explain exactly why that happens, and a workaround. Then you throw in some apparently unrelated JS that allows you to enable/disable elements. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're falling victim to a common beginner hangup in Rails. Your app is actually behaving correctly but you're expecting the wrong result.

Lets say you have a resource named `products`.

In Rails the `GET /products/1/edit` action simply renders a form. It's an [idempotent action](https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/).

When you then submit the form you send `PATCH /products/1` without the suffix. That's because in REST you use the HTTP method to convey what's happening. Not suffixes on the URL.

When you then re-render the form with errors you're displaying the result of performing a non-idempotent action. You're responding to a form submission and that response is specific to just that request.

This is not the same thing as `GET /products/1/edit` and should not have the same URL.

See:

- [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)
- [Upcase REST tutorial](https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/rest)

Answer (score 0):

It's behaving correctly. I think you're confusing the `show` url with the `update` url. They are the same, but they have different HTTP verbs. It's `GET` for `show` and `PATCH` for update.

When your validation fails, you are in the #update method in your controller, but b/c the validation fails you render the `edit` view. That's what this code does `format.html { render({:controller => :cs, :action=> :edit }) }`. Actually you could just abbreviate that to `render :edit`.

Everything is working the way it should!