# Keep model with errors when redirecting to edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When there was an error on updating my model, I was rendering :edit, but this was stripping the `/edit` from my url because `#update` is the same as `#show` with a different request method. To solve this I tried following the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348920/how-to-make-a-render-edit-call-show-the-edit-in-the-address-bar), but this caused me to get an `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` error when I try to submit an invalid form. How should I correctly re render the edit page, while keeping both the `/edit` url and the flash messages? Is it possible to check for validity and show the errors without making a call to update?

Original code:

```
def edit
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      if @model.update(model_params)
        redirect_to home_base_url_or_default(model_url(@model)), notice: "Successfully updated."
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Failing code:

```
def edit
  if flash[:model]
    @model = flash[:model]
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      if @model.update(model_params)
        redirect_to home_base_url_or_default(model_url(@model)), notice: "Successfully updated."
      else
        flash[:model] = @model
        redirect_to :action => :edit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: CookieStore in rails is 4KB in size. The error that you get is raised whenever that limit is exceeded. I encourage you to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473808/cookie-overflow-in-rails-application) out. Maybe it'll help

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing a redirect, in this case the problem was solved by doing a render, then controlling the view by setting an instance var in the controller saying if it is the edit page or not. Also by using the `update` class in the CSS. However, this still has the the url for the show page, but at least the layout is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to allow the `edit` action to accept the `POST` method as well. Use `request.method` to check whether it is a `POST` or `GET`, then perform your `render` or `redirect` accordingly.